# Java: StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when using .charAt() in for-loop

Tags: java

thank you in advance for reading about my problem.

I am making a Hangman game where I want to print out a hidden version of the current word, but I would like to update it when a correct letter is guessed (on the right spot, too). I've been looking around StackOverflow but I just can't seem to find an explaination that I understand. If someone could help me, that would be great. :D

I'll post the for-loop that this is about. I can post more of the code if you might need it. The answerInput and guessInputString are both read from the console earlier in my code using a br.readLine() method.

```
for (int i = 0; i < inputAnswer.length(); i++) {

    char inputAnswerChar = inputAnswer.charAt(i);

    char guessInputChar =guessInputString.charAt(i);

    if (inputAnswerChar == guessInputChar) {

        replacementString.replace(replacementString.charAt(i), inputAnswerChar);
    }

}
```

Thank you for any help that you can give me!

Comment: If you were to step through your code in your debugger with a simple example you would be able to see what the problem is yourself.

Comment: Thank you, i'll take a look in the debugger to see what I can find. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code is assuming that `guessInputString` and `replacementString` both have at least as many characters as `inputAnswer`, which is obviously wrong to assume, since your loop only guarantees that the `i`'th character exists for the `inputAnswer` String.

BTW, `replacementString.replace(replacementString.charAt(i), inputAnswerChar)` has no effect, since it cannot change the `String` it is executed for (since `String`s are immutable). You must assign the new `String` returned by this method back to `replacementString` :

```
replacementString = replacementString.replace(replacementString.charAt(i), inputAnswerChar)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply first of all :) Do you maybe have any idea of how I could re-write it? In steps, this is what i need it to do:

    -if inputAnswer contains guessInputString letter
      -for each character
       -if inputAnswer letter equals guessInputString letter
        -replace replacementString letter with inputAnswer letter

Comment: @bakfietsland it's hard to say without seeing more of your code. You have 3 Strings. How are they initialized? Should they all have the same length?

Comment: These 3 strings are initialized as follows:
-inputAnswer is retrieved by a br.readLine();
-guessInputString is later retrieved by a br.readLine();
-replacementString is a string that is made up of '_' characters for each letter of inputAnswer